# jquery scroll fadeIn footer, hide at bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, hide

I have a footer with a "more" prompt that fades in to prompt the user there is more content below.

It fades in on page loading, at the top of the document, if there is more content (that you need to scroll down to see).

If there is no more content down the page to scroll to it doesn't fade in (if all the content there is fits into the window at load). This is successful.

I have written it to not fade in when it gets to a paragraph at the bottom of the page. So if there is content you need to scroll down to see, it will fade in until you get to the end of the page (signaled by the paragraph '#last'). This part will not work.

Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

HTML footer:

```
<footer id="fixedmore">
 <p>more</p>
 <div class="downArrow">
 </div>
</footer>
```

HTML last paragraph

```
<p id="last">
THE END
</p>
```

CSS fixed footer

```
#fixedmore
{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    position:fixed;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-weight:500;
    font-size:14px;



    /* fallback/image non-cover color */
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);       
    /* Safari 4+, Chrome 1-9 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.05)));        
    /* Safari 5.1+, Mobile Safari, Chrome 10+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.05));      
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.05));     
    /* IE 10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.05));      
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.05));

}

    .downArrow
    {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:50px solid transparent;
        border-right:50px solid transparent;
        border-top:10px solid white;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

CSS last paragraph

```
#last
{
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
}
```

JQuery window scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#fixedmore').hide();
    var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() < distanceTop){
        $('#fixedmore').fadeIn(3000);
    }

    else{
        $('#fixedmore').hide();
    };          

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it does fire, but the scrollTop event fires when you *start* scrolling, not when you stop, which is what you want. you can test this: if you scroll to the bottom of your page, stop, and then scroll around just a little bit so that #last remains visible, you should see that #fixedmore stays hidden. The problem is, most of the time your users will be scrolling into #last from further away, so it won't fire.

[This plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/) by James Padolsey allows for special scroll events like scrollStart and (more importantly!) scrollEnds. Give it a whirl!

Comment: I made a jsfiddle to illustrate your current issue: http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/kAJC5/

Comment: Cheers for the effort, been a while since I was looking for this answer but I appreciate your time. Also, using my version of Firefox on your jsfiddle lead to a freaky screen-filling blue box! But works fine on other browsers. Taa very much.